# Why am i not being able to download VS 2013 on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013

before download starts it says "this version of Visual Studio requires a computer with a newer version of windows". what do i need do now.

Comment: Check this link -> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2013-sysrequirements-vs; just a point - why aren't you going for vs2017/2015?

Comment: make sure you have installed the Sp1 for Windows 7